# python display record as questions one by one

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying a program where There is a table named "question_master" (containing some questions) in database with a field named "Question".
My problem is here

---

I want to display the questions one by one. Like when we click the next button it will display the next question and so until all the records are displayed.

---

I extracted some knowledge from the internet and made the code upto i know,so please help me to complete my code.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor_posts = db.cursor()
questions = 1

posts = "select * from question_master LIMIT 1 OFFSET %s " %(questions)

cursor_posts.execute(posts)
db.commit()
keywords=[]
for i in cursor_posts.fetchall():
    keywords.append(i[0])
print question
questions = queestions + 1
```

I just tried,i dont know how its going to be displayed and dont know where to insert button.My aim is to display one at a time by incrementing the offset when i click on the button ,then it has to loop back to display my next question,

---

any help would be greatly appreciated.Please comment incase of any missing/inappropriate information.

---

Comment: use raw_input("please press enter to continue")

Comment: where should i use it?

Comment: _"I don't know how it's going to be displayed"_. Can't you find out by running the script? _Have_ you run this yet? It doesn't look like `question` is defined anywhere.

Comment: thats where my confusion is,thats why i needed help!

Comment: what is Question variable in your code?

Comment: So your confusion is, you don't know how to run a Python program?

Answer (score 0):

```
posts = "select * from question_master order by ID ASC" 

cursor_posts.execute(posts)
db.commit()
keywords=[]
for i in cursor_posts.fetchall():
    keywords.append(i[0])
    print question
    raw_input("please press enter to continue")
```

here raw_input() waits untill a key is pressed and no need to increment the offset

Comment: does it prints the next question present in the field? and why use "order by ID ASC"?

Comment: printing question one by one  in ascending order assuming u have id for question_master so that there is no need of incrementing questions variable

Comment: What would `print question` accomplish? It isn't defined anywhere in the code.

Comment: @kevin i have asked OP about it. still waiting for reply

Comment: @user3774272 what is question variable

Comment: if i need to loopback and consider my questions has four options to select ,does it on accending will loop over the conditions using the above code as sample or do i need to insert something new to loop for the next question?hope you underestand my question!

Comment: @user3774272 it just display question from first to last . no looping back. that wasn't provided by you in your Question

Comment: apologize...print question is done my mistake thinking that it wouls print the question from the field

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар Could you provide any link over such program or simply tell me what i need to do for looping?